# Greenplum indexing not used on query

Tags: database, indexing, greenplum

I have created a table T , which has an index created on a column C (btree index) , but when i run the select query this index is not being used.

Ex:

```
Explain select * from T where C='xxx'
```

This searches in all the segments sequentially , without considering the index which i have created.

I have used the following flags

```
enable_seqscan = off
enable_bitmapscan = off
enable_indexscan = on
```

Am I missing anything?Kindly explain?

Thanks
Ganesh.R

Comment: Please show us the execution plan, ideally from an EXPLAIN ANALZYE. You can paste it to http://explain.depesz.com/ and post the link to your plan, because then it will be easier to read. Btw: what do you mean with "*all the segments*"?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the query optimizer, for whatever reason, thinks that it's better not to use the index.  Also, you may need to do an `ANALYZE` on the table if the statistical metadata is out of date.  See [this article](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/78-Why-is-my-index-not-being-used.html) (or [others like it](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=postgresql%20not%20using%20index)) for more detailed information.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer helped, then please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

w/o `explain analyze` it is quite hard to tell why, but few points:

- GP use very high random_page_cost and seq_page_cost is 1. The default value for random_page_cost is 100 which completely discourages optimiser to use index scans
- `enable_seqscan = off` doesn't turn off seq scan completely. seq scans are just heavily
  penalised
- if table is small (100 - 10k records) it's might be faster to read it sequentially and ignore index at all

Answer (score 0):

Unlike traditional  RDBMSs, an index may not be the preferable way to access data in Greenplum.

Greenplum is tuned out of the box to prefer table scans over index scans, and you have to do a lot of tweaking to change that.  You can set additional parameters to help the GP optimizer choose indexes including `set enable_nestloop on, cpu_index_tuple_cost`  and others.  Check Appendix D of the GP Admin guide for a full set of tunable parameters.

Also, how do you have the data distributed?   That can play a part in how the optimizer is choosing to process your query.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is partitioned, there is one more possible reason for your index not being used: Your table has an index, but some or all of your partitions do not. You can check this be looking at the system view `pg_indexes`. Are there entries for the partitions?

The root cause for this problem probably is that `alter table TABLE add partition...` does *not* automatically create the indexes that you have defined for TABLE.

There are two solutions:

- `create index INDEXNAME on PARTITIONTABLENAME(ROWLIST..)` after adding a partition. Search the system view `pg_partitions` the get the `PARTITIONTABLENAME`! It's not the same as the `PARTITIONNAME`.
- Delay `create index` on your table to the point where you have added all the partitions that you will need. That's because creating an index on a table automatically creates indices on all *existing* partitions.

By the way, dropping the index on the table does not drop the indexes on the partitions.

I'm sorry I cannot give you any references to the GP Admin Guide as I'm either blind or wrong or the Admin Guide ignores this matter completely.